# R install tensorflow and keras

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, reticulate

I am trying to install the `keras` and `tensorflow` libraries from R. I have followed the [official instructions from the RStudio website](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/install/) and other similar ways.

When I finish following all the steps and use `tensorflow::tf_config()` to check that the installation was successful, the output is as follows:

```
Error: Valid installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 /home/dberm/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/bin/python3.9
 /usr/bin/python3.10
```

My code so far:

```
install.packages("keras")
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = install_python())

library(keras)
install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")

tensorflow::install_tensorflow()
tensorflow::tf_config()
```

I also tried the instructions from the RStudio website, with the same results:

```
install.packages("tensorflow")

library(reticulate)
path_to_python <- install_python()
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = path_to_python)

library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(envname = "r-reticulate")

install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")

tensorflow::tf_config()
```

As far as I can understand, my problem is that tensorflow is being instantiated in the "r-reticulate" env, but when I then run `tensorflow::tf_config()` the output tells me that it is searching in other locations without success.

I'm not clear on how to change the directory in which to search for tensorflow, as I'm new to using Python from R. I've tried other similar iterations of the code, even using solutions like `use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")`, but the result is always the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I share your pain. I got a somewhat different error message, but it was probably because I had an existing miniconda  installation of python.

Comment: See discussion here. https://github.com/t-kalinowski/deep-learning-with-R-2nd-edition-code/issues/3